# Relationship between accuracy and number of independent variable in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, accuracy, auc

I am working on classification problem **https://www.kaggle.com/henriqueyamahata/bank-marketing**
I used SAS and proc logistic ::  stepwise selection(sle=0.05,sls=0.05) procedure to reduce the variable 
Also, I removed higher VIF and correlated variable 
Here is the result:
[image]

[image]

Question: 
1- Why there is no or very little impact on Accuracy even if I removed correlated variables.
2- Why AIC Increased and AUC decreased after removing Higher VIFs variable

Final correlated variable:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is little impact on accuracy, because accuracy is a very insensitive measure to use for detecting a model improvement, since it only detects the improvement of samples that cross the threshold.

AUC decreases probably because there still some signal in the variable you have removed, thus you removed information and made your model worse.